# Run macro with xlsxwriter

Tags: python, vba, excel, xlsxwriter

Working with xlsxwriter at the moment and I successfully extracted the VBA.bin from the correct doc, and have gotten it added to the appropriate workbook. I have also opened and run the macro and had it execute successfully.

What I am wondering is, can I just run the macro with xlsxwriter without having to open the document and do it myself?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey loegare, it might be helpful to include some sample code with what you've tried so far. Also just curious, why do you need to run a macro inside the workbook, instead of just doing whatever transformation you need in python before you generate it?

Comment: Hi hannele, I unfortunately have no code that I have tried, but I've been digging into the docs and found nothing. On github the author of xlsxwriter directs all non bug related inquiries here rather than to the issues thread section.

What I need is an excel pivot table in the document that would be refreshed later when more info is added in excel. My workaround so far is I wrote a macro that creates the pivot table, runs on workbook open and deletes itself. But that feels more like a bandaid than a real solution

Comment: Ah I see, and creating pivot tables [isn't supported by xlsxwriter directly](https://my.staging.freshenv.com/#/signup/staff/e88e8fc4dd3ec05f6c0d29efecd6dc7b7bf063f7959f413d1653b4a6683eefbe). 

For xlsxwriter to support running macros I think the maintainer would need to re-implement all of the functionality in Python, so I think your workaround is actually a fairly reasonable thing.

Comment: unfortunate, because the deleting itself part is pretty finicky, and its necessary if you want it to execute on startup. thanks for your help though!